# Async call of ASMX web service

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, asmx

In my scenario when ever user changes some fields in the program and does a `SAVE`, a `webserivce` request is sent to save some logging information into the database. I did some search on the website and found this solution for `Async` calls:

```
 ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate
 {
    // Create an instance of my webservice object.
    // call its Log webmethod.
 });
```

But since I don't have much experience with `webservices` and `Async` calls so I wanted to show you the scenario I have and the way I am handling it to get your opinion about it and if it the right way to do this. Thanks for suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you tolerate the logging work to be lost? Only then should you start "background work" in an ASP.NET app.

`QueueUserWorkItem` will work. The more modern version is `Task.Run`. Make sure you catch errors that happen on that thread-pool thread. If not, you'll never find out about bugs and silently lose work.

If you expect a high volume of such calls, or expect them to take a long time, [consider using async IO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730059%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). It does not use any thread while in progress (not even a background thread).

Comment: prob because I am on .NET 4.i it doesn't show me Task.Run? But intellisence does show me Task.Factory.StartNew() . Is that good too?

Comment: That is almost the same and entirely usable. You might want to do some research around best practices regarding the task API. Doesn't take long and might save you trouble.